# Test Run Setup and Teardown

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

So currently I have the following:

TEST SCRIPT FOLDER
|----- Test Script 1.robot
|----- Test Script 2.robot
|----- Test Script 3.robot
|----- Test Script 4.robot

Currently, I have a suite setup which opens the browser and logs into my application at the start of each test script, then a suite teardown which closes the browser at the end of each test script so when I run the whole suite, it opens a browser, logs in, runs the test cases, and closes the browser for each script.

What I want to do is have it open the browser and log in, then run all the test cases in the four scripts, then close the browser once all four scripts have run.

I'm not asking how to code it, I'm just not sure how I would do it. Do I need a separate setup script that runs first and does the setup, and then a separate teardown script that runs last? Or is there a better way? I've not been able to find anything so far.

I've been researching and I've not been able to find any examples. I've tried using a script that performs each action but I'm sure there must be a better way to do it.